# Rscript call from PHP File

Tags: php, r, webserver

I'm new to R, and don't even know if this is working.
I am sending some data to a webserver. From there I want to start a R Script which does some calculation with this data
Right now I tried this in localhost and start the R Script on my laptop using this function

```
$output=shell_exec("Rscript my_script.R $a $b $c");
```

Now I have a server and R installed on it.
Is it also possible to run my R Script on the server the way I did above?

Comment: AFAIK, to run a script like that, you only need R and Rstudio server is not necessary.

Comment: That means I only have to install R on my Webserver (not Localhost)

Comment: You mention Rstudio server three time in your post like you really mean it. Can you modify the title, text and tag to reflect this?

Comment: I don't know if I need this, so I would appreciate any help how a can run a R Script somewhere on a webserver. I thought this R studio server is something to run R scripts on the web. Maybe I am wrong

Comment: R Studio server is not quite what you're talking about, so I think referring to `Rscript` is more relevant for what you need.

Comment: But do I need to install something special on this webserver so it is able to run my R Script? Right now I really don't know how to do that

Comment: For the command in your post, `R` should be all you need.